# Is there a way to cut off a part of a decimal in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I have a number that increases every second by addition. The problem is that it contains way too many decimals. An example of an output which I do not want would be something like 1.5999999999999999 or 1.600000000001. I have tried using the toFixed method, passing in 2 as it's value, and I am still getting the issue. I have also tried using the Math.round(number * 100) / 100 and am still getting uggly decimals.
How can I get an output that only contains a specified number of decimal points? I want to be able to choose how the number rounds. The function to round should be something like this:

```
function round(numberToRound, afterDecimals){
//Rounding code which takes into the account the number of decimal values I wish to display should go here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `toFixed` would work. You must not be applying it properly.

Comment: Yes, please post the code showing how you trying to use `toFixed`.

Comment: Indeed, `toFixed` should do it. Can you please show us how you tried to use `toFixed` to round your number?

Comment: ```function rnd(num1, num2)
{
return num1.toFixed(num2);
}//cf
rnd(6.38473829, 2);
```

Comment: What is the problem with that ? Do you need a `number` and `rnd` returns a `string` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry, I didn't call the function in the right place. The function works as expected, I just wasn't updating the innerHTML correctly.
Again, I am sorry for overlooking this.